# Basic intent issue?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I am trying to build an app that displays a second activity when the button is pushed. It also changes the text of a TextView in the second activity (id:baconTextId) based on text entered in the first activity's EditText (id:ApplesInput).

Activity 1 : Apples.java
Activity 2: Bacon.java

On both buttons in the xml I put

```
android:onClick = "Thismethodiscalledonclick"
```

So that I don't need to add listeners.

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=278&video=27370) on intents, but got an error. Android Studio shows no errors, but when I push the button "ApplesInput" w/ id of "ApplesInput" my phone says, "unfortunately Intent Example has stopped."

[image]

After pushing this button, I should get a screen like the following:

[image]

**First activity: Apples.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
public class Apples extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apples);

}
    public void Thismethodiscalledonclick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Bacon.class);


        final EditText ApplesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ApplesInput); //Named var and id same for simplicity

        String usersmessage = ApplesInput.getText().toString(); //Whatever user types

        i.putExtra("applesMessageKey", usersmessage); //Parameters == ("What do you want to call this", What piece of information?)



        startActivity(i); //Starts intent stuff

    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_apples, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Second Activity: Bacon.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class Bacon extends AppCompatActivity {


final TextView BaconText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BaconTextid);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bacon);

   Bundle applesData = getIntent().getExtras(); //Call intent and store the extras in applesdata

    if(applesData == null){
      BaconText.setText("Must type something, sending you back...");
        Thismethodiscalledonclick(null); //Take them back to first screen

        return;
    }

    String applesDataReceived = applesData.getString("appleMessageKey");
    BaconText.setText(applesDataReceived);
}

public void Thismethodiscalledonclick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Apples.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bacon, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Some of the logcat error filtered:

```
 android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: accessibility_enabled
        at           android.provider.Settings$Secure.getIntForUser(Settings.java:3163)
        at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getInt(Settings.java:3148)
        at com.android.systemui.power.PowerUI$1.onReceive(PowerUI.java:386)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at                  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Feel free to ask me for anymore code or resources if you think it is needed in the problem solving process.

Comment: what is the logcat output?

Comment: @Shmuel Thank you for your response, I will update my question with the logcat output. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private TextView BaconText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bacon);
    BaconText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baconText);

    Bundle applesData = getIntent().getExtras(); //Call intent and store the extras in applesdata

    if(applesData == null){
      BaconText.setText("Must type something, sending you back...");
        Thismethodiscalledonclick(null); //Take them back to first screen

        return;
    }

    String applesDataReceived = applesData.getString("applesMessageKey");
    BaconText.setText(applesDataReceived);
}

public void Thismethodiscalledonclick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Call findViewById() in onCreate().
And name putExtra in ApplesActivity is "applesMessageKey" and name getString in BaconActivity is "appleMessageKey". They not same :D

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining why I needed to put findViewById() in the onCreate() method, and why I needed to declare BaconText as private instead of final?

Comment: Also, I want to take the user back to the first activity if they don't type anything in BaconText. Right now, that isn't working - it is probably a problem with this line: Thismethodiscalledonclick(null); //Take them back to first screen. Do you mind explaining how I can fix that?

Comment: BTW: I marked your answer as best answer, and I hit like on your answer. :)

Comment: I think "final" is meant Not change, usually use to define constant.

So, findViewById() is not the method defined constants.
And applesData is not null because the Intent(this, Bacon.class) started. You can check with applesData.getString("applesMessageKey");

Comment: Then how should I call Thismethodiscalledonclick if user does not type anything in the textfield? Because if they dont type anything I want the app to go back to the first activity again. Thanks! :)

Comment: if (applesDataReceived.equals("")) { finish(); }

Call finish() to close current Activity, But that would not have happened.